# Ping and tracert misbehaving on my device only

Tags: networking, ping, traceroute

I'm posting this here instead of the networking forum because the issue is isolated on my PC

Long story short:

1. Pinging anything always results in a successful reply from my private IP
2. Any traceroute attempt results in a 2 hop route with hope 1 being the destination and hop 2 my computer

Whatever's causing this is definitely on my PC as I've tested another machine on the same network, and even booted an Ubuntu USB on my machine. Neither experienced these problems

I've tried removing the hosts file, disabling the firewall, disabling all unnecessary network adapters but nothing worked. I even checked what programs I have installed in case I could figure out what might be causing it but other than Vmware Workstation and a VPN client, there's nothing else that could potentially mess with my network setup.

Ping and tracert excerpts:

```
Pinging microsoft.com [104.215.148.63] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.10.10.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 104.215.148.63:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms


tracert microsoft.com    
Tracing route to microsoft.com [104.215.148.63]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  104.215.148.63
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  Desktop [10.10.10.10]

Trace complete.
```

I'm wondering if any of you came across such behaviour before. I could just format and start fresh but it'd be nice to know what might be causing this.

**EDIT**

As requested, here's the routing table:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 17...e0 d5 5e 67 e7 18 ......Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
  6...00 1a 7d da 71 04 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #2
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.10.10.1      10.10.10.10     25
       10.10.10.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.10.10.10    281
      10.10.10.10  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.10.10.10    281
     10.10.10.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.10.10.10    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.10.10.10    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.10.10.10    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: Show us a complete `route print`.

Comment: I have edited the original text with the routing table